# Is it correct to use main() but didn't put everything in def main():?

Tags: python, project, pyqt5

Basically, my code in `top.py` is like this. I am trying to create a PyQt5 project, and be able to test each dialog boxes / windows separately.

```
import sys, os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir('../')
    sys.path.insert(0,'.')
    #import *
else:
    pass
    #from . import *

#from common import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

def main():
    global window
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showUI()

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def showUI(self):
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is it a bad practice?

Project structure:

```
main.py
gui/
    __init__.py
    top.py
common/
    __init__.py
    common.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common design which is however technically completely optional is something like

```
def real_stuff():
    # ... your actual code ...

def main():
    # some setup when invoked from the command line
    # maybe print a hostile welcome message? (No, don't.)
    real_stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The purpose of the final conditional is to make your script possible to `import` from another script, but also possible to run with `python` from the command line.  When you `import` you don't want the program to start running immediately, so the starting point is conditional on that.

You could basically put everything you have in `def main()`: inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` instead and it would work completely the same.  When it's not *completely* trivial it's nice to have it encapsulated in a separate function so that a human reader has an easier time following the logic, but as far as Python is concerned, it's pretty much the same (apart from the trivial overhead of one additional function call).

A tangential consideration is how to make your code modular enough to be reusable. If `real_stuff()` is a useful piece of functionality which you may want to call from other programs in the future, definitely make it into a separate function which is not inside `def main()` or even inside `if __name__ == '__main__'`.  If it has snippets which could be useful for other programs in their own right, refactor those into separate functions, too, and call those when you need them from your other programs, too.

For these function to be programmatically useful, they should probably not do any user-facing interactions, so probably factor those into a separate function -- again, not necessarily inside `main()` but separate from the code which makes sense to use from other programs in the future.  Whatever remains of user interaction or startup for the code to run standalone, put in `main()` (or, again, if it's completely trivial, don't even create a separate function for it).

Comment: When calling `top.py` from `from gui import top`, what is the general way to call? `top.load()`, not `top.main()`?

Comment: I don't see a `def load` in there so on the basis of what you have shown us, the answer would be no. If there is a `load()` function which does something which from your perspective is somehow better than what `main()` does then by all means prefer that.

Comment: And maybe I should qualify this a bit by mentioning that I really don't know anything about Qt/PyQt5 or any conventions it might add to the soup.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice would be to have a "test" folder with one file per "window" to be tested. For example a "toy_test.py" file where you import all what is needed, such as "toy.py". And cut and paste the main block in this test file.

But the way you did is correct as "if main" block is invoked only if the script is the one being directly invoked.

Comment: Actually, in `main.py`, there is only 2 lines.
`from gui import top
top.main()`
Previously, I used `top.load()`, but I changed to `top.main()` when I see this possibility.
Also, I wonder if I should name the file `main.py`?

Comment: Python doesn't care what the file is named, as long as it doesn't contain characters which are problematic for `import` (dash and dot are examples, you can't `import fun-project` because the dash is not allowed in a Python identifier).  Usually, call it something which actually describes its functionality -- if this is a calculator app, `calculator.py` would be a good name.